# Using struct throws bignumber error

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
struct Student
{
    int roll;
    string name;
}
contract Test {
Student public s1;
    constructor(int n,string memory namee)
    {
        s1.roll=n;
        s1.name=namee;
        
    }
}
```

creation of Test errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.5.0)

I am a beginner and only started to learn solidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just tried your code on remix but I moved the struct Student inside your contract (on the code you provided, the structure declaration is outside of your contract), and now it works.

Looks like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract Test {
    struct Student
    {
        int roll;
        string name;
    }

    Student public s1;
    
    constructor(int n, string memory name)
    {
        s1.roll=n;
        s1.name=name;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it worked.

Comment: Great to hear! If you could mark my answer as valid so other people with the same issue can find it faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: remix example]

when you do the deploy, pls pass the parameters.for example, I pass `12,dfk`,this is your funcotion need.

try it.

and you can also find same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011183/solidity-invalid-bignumber-string-argument-value-value-code-invalid-argu

hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yeah it worked.

Comment: cheers, the answer is useful for u, that's a good news.